# How to resolve ANR while invoking a list

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which a thread will run in main thread and it will call a list of users in every 1 sec,but i am getting the pop up that **ANR**. please suggest. **How To Resolve?**

Below is my code

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mHandler = new Handler();

     Runnable runable = new Runnable() { 

            @Override 
            public void run() { 
                try{
                     listofUsers = GcmIntentService.getListOfUsers();
                    if (listofUsers.size() > 0) {
                        for (int index = 0; index < listofUsers.size(); index++) {
                            if (index == 0) {
                                startTime = listofUsers.get(0).getLoggedinDateTime();
                            } else {
                                Calendar calender1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                calender1.setTime(startTime);
                                calender1.add(Calendar.SECOND, i);
                                newTime = calender1.getTime();
                                listofUsers.get(index).setLoggedinDateTime(newTime);
                                i = i + 72;

                            }
                            ///user time is checked with the current system time.
                            Iterator<UserInformation> userDetailsIter = listofUsers.iterator();
                            Calendar calender2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                            while (userDetailsIter.hasNext()) {
                                UserInformation newUserInfo = userDetailsIter.next();
                                Date userTime=newUserInfo.getLoggedinDateTime();
                                Date systemTime=calender2.getTime();
                                if ( userTime.compareTo(systemTime) < 0 ) {
                                    userDetailsIter.remove();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                finally{
                    //also call the same runnable 
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100); 
                }
            } 
        }; 
        mHandler.postDelayed(runable, 100); 
    }
```

Please help me by guiding me about what I have done wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a while loop or any kind of long running operation on main queue

why don't you make a normal thread inside a repeated timer

like the below code

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                check();
            }

        }, 0, 100);
```

and inside check make a thread and do what ever you want

```
public void check(){
    new Thread(new new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do what you want here

            }
        }).start();
}
```